# PyCharm projects uses each others pip and python files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am working on several projects on the same PyCharm. Like I "attached" them all together. But I recently noticed some weird behaviors. Like when I import a library I haven't installed yet to my script. It shows me a little error as expected. But when I try to install that using `python -m pip install my_library`, it tells me that it has already installed. I recently noticed that this is because it's using and other pip from another project. I doesn't use the one in the `venv` folder in the project. Also to run the scripts sometimes it uses python.exe from pythons original directory. It's a whole mess and I have no idea how I can solve it. Sometimes my projects requires different versions of the same library and you can imagine what happens when I change the version.

I make sure each project is using their own interpreter. Don't know what else to do other than this. I am using Python3.6.4 PyCharm2018.3.2 running on Windows10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it sounds like all your projects are configured to use the system's interpreter instead of the `virtual environment` you set up for each of them.

Follow this instruction to fix it https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm-edu/creating-virtual-environment.html

In terms of using different version of the python library, you can address that by specifying it in `requirements.txt` file, which you can put in your `venv` folder for each project. then you can just do `pip install -r requirements.txt` after you set up your `venv`. (you need to ensure that the venv is activated - you don't need to worry about this if you have configured the project in PyCharm to use the venv's python interpreter.) You can check this by going to `Terminal` in your PyCharm and you should see `(venv_name) hostusername@host:~/project_folder$`

Comment: I am currently running a model so I will check this first thing tomorrow but this just raised couple questions in my mind. First, If they all using the system's interpreter why I am keep installing libraries. Even sometimes I have to install the same library that I install a day before. Like I've been working on this script that uses nltk for week now but today it had to install it again. Also, I followed the instructions in the link you provided and all my projects have their own virtual envs but sometimes some projects' interpreter settings just changes idk why.